# Magical record auto migration fails with an attribute of binary data in an entity

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, magicalrecord

hello guyz i am facing an issue during automigration of magical record.My scenario is.
->i added a new entity into my model and added following line for auto migration.
[MagicalRecord setupCoreDataStackWithAutoMigratingSqliteStoreNamed:@"EmergencDatabase.sqlite"];
->I added an attribute of type binary data in my new entity.(Note:for string type it works)
->when i run the app for testing , magical record failed to fetch values from existing entities .and it always fetch null values.

please help me in resolving the said issue. thanks.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ufzqe.png)

Comment: When do you add values for this binary attribute?

Comment: i didnt add values , just added attribute and run the app and it crashes because auto migration not worked.you can see the screen shot i attached above.